# Core Data NSObject to Int

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nsobject

My core data attribute for statuses is

[image]

because I want to keep the logs of the status changes. So one value won't be sufficient.

when I write data to core data like below

```
@State var statusIndexEdits : [Int] = []
@State var selectedStatusIndex: Int = 0
.onChange(of: self.selectedStatusIndex) { newValue in
                self.editItem(account: account)
            }
private func editItem(account: CDAccount) {
viewContext.performAndWait {
            if account.statusIndex != selectedStatusIndex {
                account.statusIndex = Int64(selectedStatusIndex)
                statusIndexEdits.append(selectedStatusIndex)
                account.statuses = statusIndexEdits as NSObject
                print(account.statuses!)
            }
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
    }
```

My `print(account.statuses!)` statement prints

statuses = "(\n    4,\n    1,\n    12,\n    1,\n    0,\n    5\n)";

So while trying to convert my `account.statuses`like below I can not get Int values from it.

I have tried to reach those status index values with

```
 ForEach(Array(arrayLiteral: account.statuses), id: \.self) { statusIndex in
 trial 1
//Text(self.status[statusIndex as! Int])
 trial 2
//Text("\(statusIndex ?? 0 as NSObject)")
 trial 3
//Text(status[Int("\(statusIndex ?? 0 as NSObject)")!])
 }
```

Btw if you want to know what the heck is status it is

```
@State var status : [String] = Constants.Status.status

    struct Constants {
        struct Status {
            static let status = ["Introduction", "Demonstration", "Offer submitted", "Waiting for reply", "Accepted", "Declined", "Revise offer", "Contract sent", "Contract signed", "Server setup", "Training", "Integration", "Live", "Invoice"]
    }
```

So according to the status index, I am reaching its status with `status[statusIndex]`

So long story short how can I convert those core data NSObject to Int. Thus I can use status[statusIndex] easily.

Comment: What is the goal of casting to `NSObject`?  Core Data supports native Swift types pretty well. And rather than a transformable attribute convert the stuff to JSON und convert it with a computed property.

Comment: If I just type account.statuses = statusIndexEdits I am getting error Cannot assign value of type '[Int]' to type 'NSObject' Insert as NSObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if statuses is [Int]`. Just define it as the "Custom Class" in the "Data Model Inspector". It will work like a regular array

[image]